# Inkscape 0.91 does not install on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, inkscape

Just updated from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS on an Acer E3-111. I attempted to re-install Inkscape 0.91 (stable) with the following results:

```
~$ gksudo apt install inkscape
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
inkscape : Depends: libgsl2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a fix or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, was able to fix this bug doing the following:

1. Made sure my system is updated

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
2. uninstalled everything related to inkscape, PPA's icluded.
3. downloaded the Inkscape package for Ubuntu 16.04 from  pkgs.org/download/inkscape
4. installed the package from teminal using gdebi, if you don't have it install it

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gdebi
   ```

then

```
    sudo gdebi inkscape_0.91-7ubun‌‌​‌​​tu2_amd64.deb
```

NOTE: make sure the directory in terminal is the same one where you downloaded the .deb package or you will get a "file not found" message.

It runs fine now.

All credit for fixing this bug goes to @rancho, for all the details as to how he helped you can follow this link: [unmet dependencies after upgrade to 16.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812703/unmet-dependencies-after-upgrade-to-16-04-1/812757#812757)

Hope it fixes the bug for you too.

Comment: Didn't work for me