# unmet dependencies after upgrade to 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, inkscape

the upgrade (up from 14.04) went smoothly with all installed apps, except for Inkscape, which was erased.

I've updated and used apt-get autoremove, I successfully installed the latest stable PPA from inkscape.org but when trying to install Inkscape I get the following:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies
    inkscape : Depends: libgsl2 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying to install from the Ubuntu software center the Inkscape icon appears with a "waiting to install" message, never doing anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44029/discussion-between-rancho-and-a-manc).